# Stop SQL from inserting duplicates (php)

Tags: php, sql, database, oop, pdo

It seems to be impossible to do this just with SQL statements, so I wrote a php check, which is completely ignored by the script. $resourse array holds the right data.

```
public function handleUpdates($updates) {

    $stmt = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT ? FROM users"); //<-
    $stmt->execute(["username"]); //<-
    $resource = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //<-

    foreach ($updates["result"] as $update) {

        $text = $update["message"]["text"];
        $args = $update["message"]["chat"]["username"];

        if ($text === "/start") {              
            if ($resource['username'] !== $args) //this here is ignored
                $this->database->add($args); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the content of $update["message"]? Have you tried debugging that (e.g. printing its content)?

Comment: Ignored? What are the values of `$resourse['username']` and `$args` then? It's more likely that you are getting different values to what you are expecting.

Comment: take note that table/column names cannot be bound, but you can whitelist them

Comment: `$resourse` is not the same as `$resource`

Comment: $update['message'] is a fetched Json array. The value of $args equals to 'name', value of $resourse['username'] also equals to 'name'

Comment: The result is the same despite the typo in $resource

Comment: This code `$resourse['username'] !== $args` is invalid because `$resourse['username']` is an array and `$args` I guess is a string. If you want to check if username exists in array, use `in_array` or `array_key_exists`.

Comment: `SELECT ? FROM users` its juts wrong to begin with

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember about PDO/SQL (I moved to MVC/Doctrine a while back), this part seems a little redundant

```
$stmt = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT ? FROM users"); //<-
$stmt->execute(["username"]); //<-
```

and could be replaced with

```
$stmt = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users"); //<-
```

as you're only ever wanting to get the data found in the username column there's no need to bind it (which isn't fully possible in PDO anyway).

---

The reason your query fails is that you are using `fetch` over `fetchAll` which returns only the first row of results, while this will run it won't give the desired result (which I'm guessing is to check if the username already exists). Even then (as Ivan Vartanyan points out), you would need to `foreach` or `in_array` over `$resource` as it's results are sent as an array anyway.

Realistically you don't need to search and iterate over all the data in PHP, consider searching for your passed username data with SQL instead (code untested);

```
public function handleUpdates($updates) {
    $stmt = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($update["message"]["chat"]["username"]));
    $resource = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$resource) {
        foreach ($updates["result"] as $update) {
            $text = $update["message"]["text"];
            $args = $update["message"]["chat"]["username"];
            if ($text === "/start") {   
                $this->database->add($args); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still floods the database with one and the same query (since I run this method in a while(true) loop I guess

Comment: @danielserendipity that'd about do it, do you not need to put `return true` somewhere in here?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it because it must not break the loop
`public function execute () {

        while (true) {
            $t = $this->getLastChat($this->getUpdates());
            $this->sendMessage ($t[0],$t[1]);

            $updates = $this->getUpdates();
            if (count($updates["result"]) > 0)
                $this->handleUpdates($updates);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
`

Comment: @DanielSerendipity using `while(true)` will just loop indefinitely unless you put a condition in the `while` statement or `break` in your loop somewhere

Comment: The loop musn't be stopped because this is a chat bot